# Automatic forward email

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, email2case

Hi guys need your help I am new sf development can u help me in automatic forward email in salesforce using apex for example a user from outside salesforce send email to a case if the subject of the email had a keyword 'Hello There' then if there is a keyword 'Hello There' it will automatically forward the email to sample@sample.com email. Please help me for this thank you. I tried to config this one but its not working

Comment: Please include your code in apex questions - see [help] and [ask]. It makes it much more likely that you will get an answer to your question.

Comment: I tried to config this one using workflow but its not working. I am new in apex so its hard for to imagine the process itself can u give me Idea about it. Thank you

Comment: Share what you have already tried, i.e. the config, maybe we can help with why that didn't work?

Comment: Share what have you tried so far

Comment: Ah yeah regarding of that I cannot do the workflow approach for it does have a conflict one of my process builder so I need to code for this I am having a hard time where to start. apologize

Comment: Try to go with email handlers with string functions you can able to do it.

Comment: If you are new to Apex, be sure to complete the [Trailhead tutorials](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/force_com_dev_beginner)

Answer (score -2):

I have a same requirement couple of days back like to forward an email for verification purposes.

Try to use email InboundEmailHandler to handle emails coming from specific email or destro.

```
global class CreateCaseFrmEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

        global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

            Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
            String attachment_body;
            if(email.subject.contains('Gmail Forwarding Confirmation')){
                sendVerificationEmail(email);
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void sendVerificationEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email){

            Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            List<String> sent= new List<String>();
            sent.add('pavan@sample.com');
            mail.setToAddresses(sent);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Test');

            mail.setSubject('Test');
            mail.setPlainTextBody(email.plainTextBody);
            mail.setHtmlBody(email.htmlBody);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

        }

    }
```

Comment: This is good information, but you're assuming too much of the asker. They don't seem to know very much about SF at all which means even if they could adapt your code, they don't know how to configure it so that SF actually uses the custom handler instead of the built in one. To make this more complete, you should include those steps as well. Also, this is a sort of "do it for me" question which is frowned upon and we don't want to encourage those types of questions.